# Check if pandas column contains only 0's or 1's

Tags: python, pandas

I want to know if there is a way to check whether a pandas column contains only 0's or 1's. This can be done using `df.groupby('col').count()` and then verifying that there are only two indices and checking if 0 and 1 are part of the index. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 15):

Use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with test if all values are `True`s by [`Series.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.all.html):

It returns `True` or `False` flag. See it in action here.Let's consider this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[0,1,0],
                   'col2':[2,3,1]})
print (df)
   col1  col2
0     0     2
1     1     3
2     0     1

test = df['col1'].isin([0,1]).all()
True

test = df['col2'].isin([0,1]).all()
False
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use unique() which would return all the unique values from a column

For e.g.

```
#List unique values in the df['name'] column
df.name.unique()
```

This would return an array of unique values present in that column

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) operations with [`set.issubset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset):

```
{0, 1}.issuperset(df['col'])
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [0, 1, 0]})

{0, 1}.issuperset(df['col'])
# True
```

If you have several columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 2],
                   'B': [1, 1, 1],
                   'C': [0, 1, 0]})

df.apply({0, 1}.issuperset)
# A    False
# B     True
# C     True
# dtype: bool
```